# Google App Engine Eclipse Plugin Sign in: I got a white screen

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I tried to sign in in Eclipse using the Gooel App Engine plugin but after i enter my login info i got a white screen.

(I tried to change to default browser in Eclipse with Chrome to solve the problem but the browser used is ie still.)

I have many projects (GAE) and i use different login info by project

[image]

Also, if you right click "View Source" on this white page, you can see, that there are correct answer page from Google. But, this page doesn't show correctly in browser window. So, there are no way to click page's button to complete sign in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue and had to resort to using the command prompt to deploy my project.

From the command prompt (you can use the terminal available in Eclipse) navigate to your project destination and enter the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.5\bin\appcfg.cmd" update war
```

If this is the first time you are doing this you should get a prompt requesting your email and password.

Note that if you created your app using Maven you would instead invoke the Maven command:

```
mvn appengine:update
```

Comment: it's been 2 years ago so I cannot QA your answer but looks like it's the way to go. I'll accept thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is not really solution, but workaround.
The problem related with wrong behavior of eclipse internal browser for https connections and/or certificate management.
This happens with eclipse for win64.
To avoid the problem, I use eclipse for win32 instead.