# AppEngine upload with Google Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

Since i recently reinstalled my complete Eclipse Environment (Eclipse Luna, Google Cloud Plugins, Android ADT) i am no longer able to deploy my Web Application to Google App Engine.
I am stuck with an empty 'Sign in to Google Services Window'.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse

Comment: thanks i know that page, but following that steps did not solve this problem. i tried with three different Eclipse versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Plugin for Eclipse tries to authorize through the embedded browser in Eclipse. If this fails, it tries to launch an external browser with an authorization request url. In Eclipse, check Preferences -> General -> Web browser for the current browser settings. If it is set to internal browser, try changing it to: Use external browser. That should launch an external browser with an authorization url

BTW, in my case (using Eclipse Indigo and the Google plugin for that version, the authorization URL that is passed to the external browser was malformed (http:/ instead of http:// in the url). I had to correct those manually in the url to complete the authorization and get an authorization code. You can paste this code in the plugin dialog in Eclipse to gain authorization to the Google environment.

Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565348/google-app-engine-eclipse-plugin-sign-in-i-got-a-white-screen?rq=1)