# Google Plugin for Eclipse Luna?

Tags: eclipse

I have a problem with  luna 4.4.2,
I install google plugin  when i click button login, page turn white & don't login me in google services.
Thanks.

---

I Format my pc and all goes on work :D
Thanks to all

Comment: This question has been already asked, check this link:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565348/google-app-engine-eclipse-plugin-sign-in-i-got-a-white-screen

Comment: i try and send you a response

Comment: Have you tried not using the internal browser as i mentioned in the answer? Are you running both your eclipse and browser under administrator privileges if you are using windows?

Comment: yes i try all and nothing worked :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fix I commented you or also, if you really want to use the 64 version you could always skip using the internal browser by going to Window > Web Browser and selecting the one you normally use Firefox/Chrome/etc